# Filter is not a function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing filter the data which comes from API but I am stuck at filter the data.

**here is my filter.js file**

```
import React from 'react'

  const Filter = ({
  searchInput,
  setSearchInput,
  photos,
  setFiltered
  }) => {

const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
}

const searchPhotos = (searchValue) =>{
    setSearchInput(searchValue)

if(searchInput) {
    const filterPhotos = photos.filter((photo)=>
        Object.values(photo)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
    )
    setFiltered(filterPhotos)
} else {
    setFiltered(photos)
}
}
  return (
    <>
      <section className='filter'>
            <form className='form-control' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="search" 
                name="search" 
                id="search" 
                autoComplete='off' 
                placeholder='Search Photos'
                onChange={(e)=> searchPhotos(e.target.value)}  
                />
            </form>
        </section>
    </>
)
}
export default Filter
```

**here is photos.jsx file**

(where I supposed to filter the data comes from API). On load data comes perfectly via API search query but when I type on search box it will shows error. **Uncaught TypeError: photos.filter is not a function**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Filter from './Filter';

const url = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=Nature'

const Photos = () => {

const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPhotos = async () =>{
        const res = await fetch((url),{
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'MY_API_KEY'
            }
        })
        const photos = await res.json()
        setPhotos(photos)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    fetchPhotos()
},[])
return (
   <>
        <Filter
            searchInput={searchInput}
            setSearchInput={setSearchInput}
            setFiltered={setFiltered}
            setPhotos={setPhotos}
            photos={photos}
        />

        { 
            isLoading ? (
                <h1 className='loading'>Loading...</h1>
            ) : searchInput.length > 1 ? (
                <section className="countries">
        {
            filtered.photos.map((photo,index)=>{
            return(
                <article  key={index}>
                <div className="flag">
                  <img src={photo.src.original} alt={photo.photographer} />
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                  <h4 className="country-name">
                    Photographer Name: <span>{photo.photographer}</span>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </article>
            )
        })}
                </section>
            ) : (
                <section className="countries">
                    {
                        photos.photos.map((p, index) =>{
                            const {photos, src} = p

                return(
                            <article key={index}>
                            <div className="flag">
                                <img src={p.src.original} alt={p.photographer} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="details">
                            <h4 className="country-name">
                                Photographer Name: <span>{p.photographer}</span>
                            </h4>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    )
                        })
                    }
                </section>
            )
        }

        
   </>
)
}
export default Photos
```

**API Data is**

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 15,
"photos": [
    {
        "id": 15286,
        "width": 2500,
        "height": 1667,
        "url": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-walking-between-green-forest-trees-15286/",
        "photographer": "Luis del Río",
        "photographer_url": "https://www.pexels.com/@luisdelrio",
        "photographer_id": 1081,
        "avg_color": "#283419",
        "src": {
            "original": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg",
            "large2x": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
            "large": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940",
            "medium": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
            "small": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=130",
            "portrait": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800",
            "landscape": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200",
            "tiny": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&fit=crop&h=200&w=280"
        },
        "liked": false,
        "alt": "Person Walking Between Green Forest Trees"
    },
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the API data has a key photos, which actually contains your data. So what you should do is `photos = (await res.json()).photos` and then `setPhotos(photos)`

Comment: not satisfied with this solution my issue is in Filter.jsx file not in Photos.jsx file and error occurs in const filterPhotos = photos.filter((photo) here in if condition in filter.jsx file please let me know if any solution you found.

Comment: okay before you call filter, try `conosle.log(photos)`. And you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed incorrect is you're using `useState` for photos `const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);` and then you've tried to create a new const variable called photos here:

```
const photos = await res.json()
setPhotos(photos)
```

Change that to this:

```
setPhotos(await res.json())
```

The second thing incorrect is you aren't assigning the key `photos` from the JSON to the variable `photos`, you are assigning the whole JSON object.

Edit:

To fix this change this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPhotos = async () =>{
        const res = await fetch((url),{
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'MY_API_KEY'
            }
        })
        const photos = await res.json()
        setPhotos(photos)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    fetchPhotos()
},[])
```

To this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        setPhotos(data.photos)
    });
```

Comment: not satisfied with this solution my issue is in Filter.jsx file not in Photos.jsx file and error occurs in const filterPhotos = photos.filter((photo) here in if condition in filter.jsx file please let me know if any solution you found.

Comment: Have you even tried the solution? The reason `photos.filter()` isn't working is because you are doing this `await res.json()` instead of this `await res.json().photos`

Comment: Yes I tried this solution await res.json().photos but it will throw the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'photos') in Photos.jsx file at map method.

Comment: I've modified answer.

Comment: Thanks brother now it's working fine

Comment: Happy to help. Could you mark this as the accepted answer.